# Gradle sync failed: Build tools download failed with code 2

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I just install the latest version of Android SDK but my project was made in  a old version

This is my code:

[image: code]

This is the error that is shown on my Event Log:

[image: logs]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the build Gradle version in Project: appname.gradle to the latest version and added the latest google version.

`dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
}`

You can find the latest versions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

I also updated the distrubution Url in gradle.wrapper to the latest version:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`